# How to open a file with Application.Close?

Tags: vba, excel

I stupidly put `Application.Close` to run when WB is opening and now I can't get to my own file and code. What do I do?

Macro in *ThisWorkbook*:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Application.Close
End Sub
```

Comment: Might sound like a silly request, but what version of Excel are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply disable macros in Excel, open the file and erase the line :)

More information on disabling macros:

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/enable-or-disable-macros-in-office-files-12b036fd-d140-4e74-b45e-16fed1a7e5c6

Comment: It worked although I had to also 'clear all Trusted documents' in Trust Center settings.